# if the Text field is blank then i want user to enter date with msgbox message

Tags: ms-access

I have a text224 in a MS access form. 
I want to check if the user is entering date or not. If date is not entered then i want to force user to enter date. 
I tried this code and it is not working.

```
Private Sub Command240_Click()
   If Me.Text224 = "" Then
        MsgBox "Date is blank"
   Else
        MsgBox "date function not working "
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Use InputBox for user input, not MsgBox. Should probably test for Null instead of empty string. Validating user input to InputBox is tricky. Recommend instead that code just gives user message and then sets focus on the textbox. Use form BeforeUpdate event to validate data. Why would user click the button? Give controls more meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle the user input, for example:

```vba
Private Sub Command240_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.Text224) Then
        MsgBox "Before I can Command240, you must enter a Text224.", vbExclamation
    ElseIf Not IsDate(Me.Text224) Then
        MsgBox "The Text224 you entered is invalid.", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "You have entered a valid Text224, but for some reason I can't Command240."
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, there is a way to name your controls.

Comment: Kudos for those educating prompts!